# Can't import Obj-C framework in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I install LGSideMenuController to Swift project with Cocoa Pods.
I created bridging header, and added following:

```
#import <LGSideMenuController/LGSideMenuController.h>

#import "UIViewController+LGSideMenuController.h"
```

However, xcode highlight  `#import "UIViewController+LGSideMenuController.h"` and says that file not found.

But file exist in pods directory. How to fix that?

Note. I already fix issue with `#import "LGSideMenuController.h"`, maked it `#import <LGSideMenuController/LGSideMenuController.h>` instead
But for `#import "UIViewController+LGSideMenuController.h"` that have no effect and error isn't gone.

Comment: And why didn't you try the same with UIViewController+LGSideMenuController.h?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad obviously i tried but not  succeed.

Comment: It is not obvious unless you wrote it. Please, add this information to your Q and write the error you got (likely the same), too.

Comment: Try this   #import <LGSideMenuController/UIViewController+LGSideMenuController.h>

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad sry, i will edit answer.

Comment: @JonSnow doesn't work

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban try this. import LGSideMenuController //OR import LGSideMenuController.LGSideMenuController

Comment: Do you find the file on disk?

Comment: Can i say something? can you add  `use_frameworks!` in your pod file it should defiantly work & fire `pod update` command

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad yes.

Comment: @mukesh_lokare thank for your help. use_frameworks! is setted on. But i gived up with that, and import Reside Menu (although used rounded brackets to import it like #import <RESideMenu/RESideMenu.h>

Answer (score 1):

Did you set your bridging header in build settings

[image: Settings]